# Best practice to restrict unauthorized users from accessing instances inside private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

What would be the best practice to restrict unauthorized users from accessing into different instances inside private subnet of AWS VPC? The private key I created for a bastion host is the only key which allows me access to instances inside private subnet through the bastion host, which means everyone who has the private key of the bastion host can have access to all the instances inside the private subnet using the private key of the Bastion Host. The private keys I had created for the instances inside the private subnet is not allowing me to login into the instances without saving the keys in the bastion host. Please help.

Comment: Unusual request. Maybe two bastion hosts, one for you and one for the others, and also set up a security group (SG) on the private subnet hosts that only allows inbound port 22 from the SG that your bastion is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The private keys I had created for the instances inside the private subnet is not allowing me to login into the instances without saving the keys in the bastion host."*

This is the root of your problem.  This is **not** needed.  By connecting to the bastion and then to the internal machine, you're essentially doing things the hard way and not taking advantage of all that ssh can do for you.

Without the private machine's ssh key on the bastion host, from outside, do all of this on one line:

```
ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -i bastion-key.pem bastion-user@bastion-ip nc %h %p' 
    -i private-instance-key.pem 
    private-username@private-instance-ip
```

You need both keys locally, and this logs you *directly* into the private instance, using an SSH proxy connection to the bastion host.

`ProxyCommand` can also be configured in `~/.ssh/config`, allowing you to simply use `ssh private-username@private-instance-ip` from your local machine.  This works even when `private-instance-ip` is not directly accessible from your local machine.  SSH does all the work.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response with the solution. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most secure way to do it is configuring a VPN connection with you VPC.
The private key would be in your hands and the VPN connection would be established only from your network. Finally the instances (Security Groups and Nacls) would only allow ssh from your IP address.